# Approach for developer-supplied, user updated lists on iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, list, app-store

I'm about to embark on my second iOS app and I need to store some lists which I will provide with the application but I want the user to be able to add to. Here are the key points.

- One list is a simple key/value list. The key is a string the user will see and select from, the value is a float.
- One list is four values per entry with no key. The values are two integers and two floats. I may allow the user to add a description which will appear in the pick list, but I expect to sort the list by the numbers. I guess I may need a hidden key for this list.
- I will provide a substantial number of entries for each list with the application (tens or hundreds of entries each).
- I expect to provide updated lists with application updates.
- I need to allow the user to add their own entries to both lists.
- When the application (and developer-provided list) is updated, the user must not lose their additions.

As implied above I'm pretty new to the whole Objective-C & iOS thing, but I can find my way around SQL just fine in the general sense. What is the best approach to this? Core Data or MySQL or something else? How do I integrate delivered (via app store update) and locally entered data, or do I keep it well separate and integrate when I build the lists? I will also have some amount of more persistent setting data to store which will likely just be a handful of key-value pairs.

Performance doesn't need to be rocket fast as these selections will be occasional for the user. Oh, and I can see it might be useful to sync the user data via iCloud, but that's not a must-have.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible solutions to this.

Core Data usually uses SQL as it's "backing store", so in essence Core Data IS SQL.

We have an app in the app store that includes a "starter" SQL database in the app bundle that is the data for our Core Data database. At launch, we check to see if the SQL file for our Core Data database exists in the documents directory. If not, we copy the file from the bundle into the documents directory. Then we fall into the code that opens the Core Data database.

The user can then use the app to modify the database contents and those changes are saved to the read/write file in the documents directory.

That approach would solve the first part of your problem. Then you have a problem with shipping updates to your app. You will need some sort of transaction system, or some way of keeping track of what contents are new and what contents are pre-existing. I guess you could ship an app update with the version 1.0 database and a separate database file of updates. Also save a "last version launched" record to user defaults. If you detect on launch that this is the first time running a new version, run a merge process that would copy the records from the update database in the bundle into the existing database in the documents directory. (You might need to copy the updates database into a temporary directory since I'm not sure the SQL engine could handle opening a read-only database file from the bundle)

Comment: Thanks. A lot of useful thinking in there. I dabble in enterprise databases in my day job so much of it makes instant sense, but the bits about the documents directory are particularly useful for me. Time to read up on Core Data.